# php/mySQL error: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to INSERT INTO a mySQL database and I'm getting this error on:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($login) == 1){
```

Here is the php, The php does add the user to the database. I can't figure it out.

```
<?
session_start();
require("config.php");

$u = $_GET['username'];
$pw = $_GET['password'];
$pwh = $_GET['passwordhint'];
$em = $_GET['email'];
$zc = $_GET['zipcode'];


$check = "INSERT INTO family (loginName, email, password, passwordhint, location) VALUES ('$u', '$pw', '$pwh', '$em', '$zc')";


$login = mysql_query($check, $link) or die(mysql_error());


if (mysql_num_rows($login) == 1) {
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($login);
echo 'Yes';exit;


} else {
echo 'No';exit;
}

mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing an `INSERT` query, so `$login` won't contain any result set, it's either `true` or `false`.

So instead of this:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($login) == 1) {
```

You can either do this:

```
if (mysql_affected_rows($link) == 1) {
```

Or this:

```
if ($login == true) {
```

Also, you don't need this line anymore:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($login);
```

Unrelated to your question, but a very important thing to remember when doing SQL queries: you'll need to escape all your `$_GET` data with [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) just before inserting, so as to prevent [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query()` returns True/False for INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP...